# Is DML allowed in the current context?

Tags: dml, exception, executioncontext

So I can check for isbatch, isfuture, etc...

Is there a way to know if the current context allows DML?  We've implemented a exception logging object, but if a class is called from a getter or constructor, it can't save the exceptions.

Yeah, I can put it in a try/catch, but why even try if I know I can't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of limitations that aren't exposed in code, including the ability to know if DML is currently allowed. The best that you *could* do would be to specifically enable or disable logging. For example, you might have a function that enables logging, and use it as the last line of a constuctor:

```
public class Logger {
    static boolean enabled = false;
    public static void enable() {
        enabled = true;
    }
    public static void log(Object data) {
        if(enabled) {
            // store the results
        }
    }
}
```

However, this requires discipline and consistent usage to be useful.